# How to make the Better Exposed Filter work as a link

Tags: theming

I installed Better Exposed Filter module in my project. I have some taxonomy term based on which the filtering is working. I have change the background for the Taxonomy term display name by altering the css file. But when I am hovering the cursor on the filtered display name, only the title of the taxonomy term is working  as a link but not the whole  as a link. What the changes I had made in the css it's not working as a link. How can I make the whole

as a link ?

Comment: What is there next to the term title that you want to be inside the link? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Hi. What you are showing above is: `<li><a href="">as a link</a></li>`, what it seems you are asking for is: `<a href=""><li>as a link</li></a>`. This is incorrect nesting of elements as `<li>` needs to be the direct descendant of a `<ul>`.  As a general reply to your question, if the 'HTML list', 'table', or other 'display' options for a view does not provide the markup you desire or need, you will need to do custom theming of views template files, or custom preprocessing of the rendering array elements. The 'advanced' tab in the view, should have rendering options for your exposed filters.